Tiny tileserver with geojson-vt
I am using geojson-vt to build a tiled db of GeoJSON and my own little tileserver. I have mostly succeeded, but am hampered by what is likely my own gap in understanding the indexing process.
Here is what I have done that works --

Downloaded countries-coastline-1m.geo.json which is 102 MB on my laptop.
Generated a tileIndex with geojson-vt and, for kicks, wrote it out to the disk where it occupies 300+ MB. I used the following options
const options = {
     maxZoom: 10,
     indexMaxZoom: 10,

     // a sensible default is 100000, but set it to 0 to generate 
     // all tiles between `indexMaxZoom` and `maxZoom`
     indexMaxPoints: 0
}


Created a simple SQLite db and filled it up the tiles converted to protobuf using vtpbf
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "countries-coastline-1m" (
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     z INTEGER,
     x INTEGER,
     y INTEGER,
     tile BLOB
 );
 CREATE INDEX "idx_countries-coastline-1m" ON "countries-coastline-1m" (
     z, x, y, tile
 );

Note: the SQLite db is ~230 MB
Wrote a little nodejs app to serve tiles from the db that are queried by a simple Leafletjs page as follows
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid@latest/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js"></script>

<script type="module">
    const map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 1);

    const options = {
        maxZoom: 14,
        vectorTileLayerStyles: {

            // A plain set of L.Path options.
            "countries-coastline-1m": {
                weight: 1,
                color: '#444',
                fillColor: '#f5f5f5',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fill: true
            }
        }
    };

    L.vectorGrid.protobuf(`http://localhost:3000/{z}/{x}/{y}`, options).addTo(map);
</script>



Now, here are the problems I am experiencing. Since I have created an index only up to maxZoom 10, but am allowing my map to go up to a maxZoom of 14, understandably, my map goes blank when it goes past 10. If instead of serving the tiles from a db, I serve them directly by generating them dynamically with geojson-vt, I get errors in the browser console past zoom level 5 because geojson-vt's default maxZoom is 5. And, even at level 5, the memory use of the process goes up very high because the index, as I mentioned above, is > 300MB.
From reading the docs, it seems one is expected to send back the entire GeoJSON file to the browser so geojson-vt can index it and slice it up at whatever zoomlevel the user requests. But, sending the entire GeoJSON is not desirable, and certainly defeats the purpose of a tileserver.
So, my question is -- if using geojson-vt, what is one to do for zoom levels past what were used to create the index?
On a related note, when I tried the above technique (building a db) with earth-waterbodies-1m, that too works, but not as well as "countries-coastline-1m". In fact, my browser just locks up when sending tiles for "earth-waterbodies-1m" and I haven't yet figured out why.
I guess meta-question is -- what is the best way to fill up SQLite db with tiles that are compatible with Leaflet? I tried the above technique with mbtiles downloaded from natural earth, but have not yet succeeded in displaying them with Leaflet.

The best way to create vector tile form GeoJSON is probably Tippecanoe: https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe. Dont't forget to use -pC flag to create uncompressed tiles, so they can be used with L.vectorGrid.protobuf.

thanks, will try that out with Natural Earth data
